# Java program that takes an input a color code in HSV and outputs the equivalent RGB code and Vice versa

Tags: java, if-statement, nested, conditional-statements

i am trying to write a code that transfer from the colour rgb to hsv but the compiler doesn't seem to see what's inside the if coundition 
here's the code
package Problem2;

```
public class HSVRGB {

    double d;
    double e;
    double g;

 //Java program that takes an input a color code in HSV and
```

outputs the equivalent RGB code and Vice versa.

```
public static void convert(double d,double e,double g){ /// my hsv inputs that am gonna check

    double t;
    double p ;
    double q;
    double f;
    double Hi;
    //my other variable am gonna use to produce the output

    Hi=(d/60);
    f=(d/60)-Hi;// here's the formula that will proceed the code




    if(Hi==0) {
        t=g*(1-(1-f)*e);
        p=g*(1-e);
        System.out.print("R="+ g + "G=" + t + "b=" + p );
        // the given input should pass into the above if condition since its true



    }
    else 
        if(Hi==1){
            q=g*(1-f*e);
            p=1-e;
            System.out.print("R="+q+"G="+g+"b="+p);



        }
        else
            if(Hi==2){
                p=g*(1-e);
                t=g*(1-(1-f)*e);
                System.out.print("R="+p + "G="+ g + "B="+t);
            }
            else 
                if(Hi==3){
                    p=g*(1-e);
                    q=g*(1-(f*e));
                    System.out.print("R="+p + "G="+q + "B=" + g );


                }
                else
                    if(Hi==4){
                        t=g*(1-(1-f)*e);
                        p=g*(1-e);
                        System.out.print("R"+t+"G"+p+"B"+g);

                    }
                    else 
                        if(Hi==5){
                            p=g*(1-e);
                            q=g*(1-(f*e));
                            System.out.print("R="+g+ " G"+p+"B="+q );


                        }
                        else
                            System.out.print("Invalid Inpjdsnabfvkdbfjsv,hdbut"); //it only print this message


}


public static void main (String[]args){
    convert(100.34,0.74,0.78);

   }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `Color.getHSBColor()` with the RGB components?

Answer (score 0):

**Here**

```
convert(100.34,0.74,0.78);
```

value of variable `d` is going to be `100.34` after that

```
Hi=(d/60);
```

value of variable  `Hi` is going to be `1.6723333333333334`

in your if statement that you have for example

```
else 
        if(Hi==1){
```

do you think value of variable `Hi` which is `1.6723333333333334` going to **be equal** to `1` ?

**Suggestion**: I really do not know why you try to compare the double to int but you can do casting or may be try to compare the range like between this and that